# return statement is not working properly in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, return, return-value

```
def chek(name):
    for i in range(3):
        print(name)
        print(i)
        if i == 1:
            chek(name="name2")
        elif name == 'name2':
            print("changed name: ",name)
            return name

s = chek("name1")

print("final name:",s)
```

In this code my expected output is :

```
name1
0
name1
1
name2
0
changed name: name2
final name: name2
```

Actual output is :

```
name1
0
name1
1
name2
0
changed name:  name2
name1
2
final name:  None
```

Can anyone help me to understand,
is anything wrong in my code or  it's is behavior

Comment: Notice how your function doesn't `return` anything `if i == 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with updating this part:

```
if i == 1:
    return chek(name="name2")
```

this would return the second `check()` calling value;

Comment: thanks, i got the flow
`if i == 1:
            chek(name="name2")`
this returns 'name2'
which i was not return again to exit the loop
and it resume the for loop where it got stop
then it don't meet both the condition
and hence return `None`

thnks